# Is there an international ppc system which allows private persons to advertise their personal websites?

Tags: advertising

I live in the European Union. I have a personal website about my home country's culture, habits, etc. written in Japanese and I want to advertise it for japanese users.

I have no experience in advertising my own site, so this would be the first occasion.

First, I tried Google Ads, but I wasn't able to choose individual account. The system forced me to use business account, which I can't do obviously, because I'm not a business owner. It turned out, that private persons can't use Google Ads in my country.

I took a brief look at Yahoo! JAPAN Promotional Ads and Microsoft Advertising and it seems that these can be used only with business account, as well.

Could you recommend me an advertising system with which I can advertise my personal website in Japan from the EU? Any advice, idea is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe study search engine optimization (SEO) ? But, are you sure that you can't  use a Gogle Ads business account? What info are they asking for that you can't provide?

Comment: SEO is fully done, but I want to speed up things, that's why I'm searching for advertising options.

Comment: Yes, sure. I double cheched it. I also created a new account to check if I made a mistake in my existing account. Finally I asked the Google Ads Community. So, 100% sure.

They are asking for the name of the company/business. I guess it's required for billing/taxes.

Comment: Can't you be "almafa, trsading as Almafa Software"? I think that you can in most countries. What's the worst that can happen if you fake a company name? You are not going to go to jail.  I am a freelance developer with my own $/£/Eur 100 company (but I have to pay an accountant to file returns annually, so that may not be a solution for you); I have signed up for many things that require company name, but none of them ever asked for a company number (would, for instance, Microsoft, even know how to check up on a company registered in Malaysia?). -->

Comment: -_> I think that Google Ads are more interested in a bank account than a company registration number.  Just invent a company name, start the application process and see if there is some killer question that you cannot answer. If none, go ahead.

Comment: In theory, it might be on option, but I'm not sure I want to go in this direction. The rules are quite strict within the EU and I want to find a "long-term headache-free" solution. (I mean not risking any account.)
Anyway, thx for sharing your suggestion.

Comment: maybe speak to an accountant? "trading as" should be fine. A Ltd / GmbH /etc costs about Eur 100 off the shelf, but annual accounts will cost a few Eur 100 for an accountant to prepare them, so might not be worth it, unless you make a lot of money from ads

Comment: Thx for the tip! Another option would be for me is to find someone, who owns a business and ask to run my ads.
But still looking for an ad system where I can do it on my own.